# Bottle server not completely resetting, holding on to old, incorrect function

Tags: python, web-applications, bottle

I've got a bottle server running, and added a function to it. The first time I made a mistake in the function - I had 4 input parameters but only passed it one. So it crashed and gave me this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle-0.11.6-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle-0.11.6-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle-0.11.6-py2.7.egg\bottle.py", line 2294, in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\aschmitt\Dropbox\Python\MyBottle.py", line 93, in edit_item
    Synopsis = result[8]
TypeError: MakeComment() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Fair enough, so I went and fixed that error. But the server doesn't recognize that I've fixed it! Just like my girlfriend, it's remembering some tiny mistake I made ages ago. It keeps giving me that same error even though it's definitely fixed - I know it's fixed because when I run the same code on a different computer it works.

It's as though it's caching the pages - it goes to them even after the bottle server is shut down. I've tried using `TEMPLATES.clear()` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Similarly with clearing the cache in Chrome. I am (and always was) running it in debug mode with the reloader (ie: `run(reloader = True, debug = True)`).

Maybe it's a matter of rebooting my computer, something I haven't tried yet. But to be honest, I don't want to have to reboot every time I make a mistake in the code.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: "...it goes to them even after the bottle server is shut down" -- that line is telling.  You mean your server responds from the dead?  How are you running your bottle server?  (Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with bottle on Windows.)  Are you sure you're shutting it down properly?  Can you check to see if there's any `bottle` process still running?

Comment: I'm running it from [Wing IDE](http://wingware.com/). I checked for obvious looking processes but didn't notice any, there were plenty that I didn't know what they did though so I guess it could have been one of them. Maybe a reboot is my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just converting my comment into an answer.)

> Are you sure you're shutting it down properly? Can you check to see if
>   there's any bottle process still running?

Answer (score 0):

Ron was correct, when I went back through the process list more carefully there was a python instance still running. After I killed that and restarted the server, it was using the right code.
Thanks Ron!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! Cheers.

Comment: (Dang, I should've made my comment an official answer. :)

Comment: Haha, if you post it again I'll tick it

Comment: Thanks for offering!  It's a little gauche, but I could use the rep so maybe I will.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexS - why have you not selected Ron's answer? I see you've accepted yours as the right one.

Comment: @Helen - I just posted my answer an hour before you noticed it; I think Alex just hasn't seen it yet. Thanks for looking out for me, though! :)